# Query a table of domain names to get matching top level domains using index

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I need to have a table that will contain a single column with a domain+suffix that will looks something like this:

| domain_and_suffix |
| --- |
| google.com |
| ynet.co.il |
| 360.cn |

I want to be able to query this table using full domain names (`photos.api.google.com`, `www.ynet.co.il`, `bla.bla.dd.cc.360.cn`) in order to get matches from the table.

I managed to make it work like this:

```
create table sites(domain_and_suffix text);

insert into sites values ('google com'),('ynet co il'),('360 cn');


with s(d) as (
    VALUES
        (to_tsvector('ddd ddd amazon com')),
        (to_tsvector('www ynet co il')),
        (to_tsvector('ccc aaa google com')),
        (to_tsvector('bla bla dd cc 360 cn'))
)
select *
from s inner join sites on (s.d @@ plainto_tsquery(sites.domain_and_suffix));
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tG7Y5xUXXGgEqyMo7RbuxN/2

My issue is that I want to be able to do this search using an index.
I can't find a decent way to do it by postfix matching, regular expression, SP-GIST using radix tree, or any other way because I need to store the "postfix" in the table and query using the values to match.

So for example, if I want to go with the approach of SP-GIST using radix tree (from [here](https://habr.com/en/company/postgrespro/blog/446624/)) I can't as the full text is being used to query and the pattern is being stored in the DB table.

I'm using PostgreSQL 12.

Comment: @jkavalik reverse them and then what? I thought about it but reversing the string means I just change my problem from suffix to prefix.

Comment: @jkavalik yeah - thats what i cant figure our =\

Comment: another idea - do sort of a tree structure - when you have "google com" and "yahoo com", store "com" as one node and "google" and "yahoo" as it children nodes. Then when searching for "www google com", you can split and reverse the list and search the tree (self joins or probably better a recursive cte)

Comment: @jkavalik can you share an example please? i tried this direction as well (also shared that link for the article that gave an example on using SP-GIST radix tree https://habr.com/en/company/postgrespro/blog/446624/) but I could not find a way to make it work.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tG7Y5xUXXGgEqyMo7RbuxN/5 - just some cte work showing some ideas, not index-efficient

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tG7Y5xUXXGgEqyMo7RbuxN/6 - in this version I removed the cte that created the entire sites tree and match it by levels instead, so only referenced ones may be fetched (by text and parent_id), then the distinct-on ensures only the longest match is returned

Comment: @jkavalik thanks for it!  but i think the performance of such query will be way higher then using FTS with no indexes as is did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way: generate all sub-domains, top-level down, and take the first match:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT ord, string_agg(label, '.') OVER (ORDER BY ord ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS subdomain
   FROM   unnest(string_to_array('bla.bla.dd.cc.360.cn', '.')) WITH ORDINALITY AS x(label, ord)
   ORDER  BY ord DESC
   OFFSET 1  -- skip tld
   )
SELECT s.*
FROM   cte c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT domain_and_suffix FROM sites s
   WHERE  s.domain_and_suffix = c.subdomain
   ) s
ORDER  BY c.ord DESC
LIMIT  1;  -- take only top-level match (?)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cccf3bd78644249962e50b7866cf534f)*

Only needs a plain btree index on `sites.domain_and_suffix`. A `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `domain_and_suffix` creates that index implicitly. If the table is `VACCUM`'ed enough, you'll see **lightning-fast index-only scans**.

The CTE is one way to generate a set of sub-domains. In Postgres 14 or later, use [`string_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) instead of `unnest(string_to_array())`.

If you use this query a lot, I suggest to write a faster **custom set-returning function** for the part. Could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_subdomains(_domain text)
  RETURNS TABLE(subdomain text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _arr text[] := string_to_array($1, '.');
   _idx int    := cardinality(_arr);
BEGIN
   subdomain := _arr[_idx];
   WHILE _idx > 1 LOOP
      _idx := _idx - 1;
      subdomain := _arr[_idx] || '.' || subdomain; 
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Excludes the TLD like above.
Then the query is simply:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM   f_subdomains('bla.bla.dd.cc.360.cn') d
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT domain_and_suffix FROM sites s
   WHERE  s.domain_and_suffix = d.subdomain
   ) s
LIMIT  1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cccf3bd78644249962e50b7866cf534f)*

Relies on the order of rows as returned from the set-returning function. Which works. If you don't trust it (not strictly standard SQL without `ORDER BY`) add `WITH ORDINALITY` and add an outer `ORDER BY` like above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! it looks almost what I needed. The only part I'm missing here is how do I use multiple values and not a single one as I saw in your example. Also, will it work faster then what I suggested using FTS when I have a table of say 10K entries and querying it using a batch of 100 domains?

Comment: The speed of index-only scans on a B-tree index is practically unsurpassable. B-tree indices are also typically smaller and cheaper to maintain than the GiST or GIN index you need for FTS. But the proof of the pudding is in the eating. Run your own performance comparison. And drop a comment here with results. :) Also: easy to extend to multi-row input ... (I am out for now.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - unless I've made a schoolboy error, your code doesn't appear to be fully functional - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e7673a4eabcc047260b8d1965c683b09).

Comment: @Vérace: `'360 cn'` <> `'360.cn'` :) I did provide a fiddle without that error ...

Comment: My apologies - I took the sites from the question and then the rest from your fiddle. :-) This mix up is what led me to accusing you in error! :-) Ignosce!

Comment: @DrorMoyal: I added a function that does not require Postgres 14 (since you declared Postgres 12).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter amazing! thanks!